# MySQL regex only returns a single row

Tags: mysql, regex

I have been writing a REGEX in MySQL to identify those domains that have a .com TLD. The URLs are usually of the form

```
http://example.com/
```

The regex I came up with looks like this:

```
REGEXP '[[.colon.]][[.slash.]][[.slash.]]([:alnum:]+)[[...]]com[[./.]]'
```

The reason we match the :// is so that we don't pick up URLs such as `http://example.com/error.com/wrong.com`

Therefore my query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM table 
WHERE name REGEXP '[[.colon.]][[.slash.]][[.slash.]]([:alnum:]+)[[...]]com[[./.]]'"
```

However, this is returning only a single row when it should really be returning many more (upwards of a thousand). What mistake am I making with the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if that's the problem, but it should be `[[:alnum:]]`, not `[:alnum:]`

Comment: Erk. Well done, it seems as if I read the documentation wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your current query only matches `name`s that end with `.com/` rather than `.com` followed by anything that starts with a slash. Try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM table 
WHERE name REGEXP '[[.colon.]][[.slash.]][[.slash.]]([:alnum:]+)[[...]]com([[./.]].*)?'"
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be clearer to split the URL rather than regexing it

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX((SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,'/',3),'.',-1)='com';
```